# Textfield remains focused after keyboard is dismissed?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my case i have used textfield for searching , when user click on it keyboard appears and when the user press back button the keyboard is dissapeared but the textfield remains focused . And when user open the drawer and close it the keyboard appears automatically .

```
SizedBox(
      height: 40,
      child:  TextField(
          onChanged: (val) {
          print(val);
          },
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
           hintText:AppLocalizations.of(context)!.searchnameoremail,
              // hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
              fillColor: Theme.of(context).dialogBackgroundColor,
              filled: true,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              suffixIcon: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(defaultPadding - 2),
                child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/Search.svg",
                    color: Theme.of(context).dialogBackgroundColor),
              )
             
              ),
        ),
      
    );
```

Comment: Add your code for better understanding of your problem statement.

Comment: added the code above , please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
keyboardSubscription = keyboardVisibilityController.onChange.listen((bool visible) {
  if (!visible) {
    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add below line:

```
FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to unfocus Keyboard. In simple words dismiss keyboard

Use it like this

```
hideKeyBoard(BuildContext context) {
  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
}
```

call this hide keyboard method when you are tapping on back button.

Answer (score 0):

FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
_textEditingController.clear();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).